# Fill with Nan when Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I want a dataframe that looks like this.

```
 a         b
cars      New
bikes     nan
trains    nan
```

Assume the following...

```
list(oldDF["Transportation"].unique())=["cars", "bikes", "trains"]
list(oldDF["Condition"].unique())=["New"]
```

My Code Looks like this Currently:

```
newList=["Transportation", "Condition"]
newDF=pf.DataFrame(columns=newList)

for i in newList:
    newDF[i]= list(oldDF[i].unique())
```

I want to be able to print the dataframe above and fill missing values with nan rather than getting a value error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `from_dict` and `orient='index'`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({n: c.unique() for n, c in oldDF.iteritems()}, orient='index').T

  Transportation Condition
0           cars       New
1          bikes      None
2         trains      None
```

---

#### `zip_longest`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

pd.DataFrame([*zip_longest(*map(pd.unique, map(oldDF.get, oldDF)))], columns=[*oldDF])

  Transportation Condition
0           cars       New
1          bikes      None
2         trains      None
```

Comment: is the .T at the end of the first line a typo? If not what does it do?

Comment: It is the transpose.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like a hidden `pivot` problem

```
oldDF.melt().drop_duplicates().\
      assign(index=lambda x : x.groupby('variable').cumcount()).\
            pivot('index','variable','value')
Out[62]: 
variable Condition Transportation
index                            
0              New           cars
1              NaN          bikes
2              NaN         trains
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not want it to have the same answer repeated multiple times. Say it could have the conditions of either new or old. In that case I would only want two rows of Condition to have values and the third to be Nan

Comment: If you look you will notice that i am only taking the unique values form the oldDF for that reason. I would appreciate it if you could adjust your code accordingly. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

use the fillna method to fill missing values with your choosing.

```
df['Condition'] = df['Condition'].fillna('')
```

Comment: That's not what OP is asking.